# Any good testing framework with distrubuted environment support?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests

I am looking form a test automation frameowrk which can work in Clinet/Server architecture (distributed env) and support a mix of operating systems like Windows, unix/linux and Mac
I am currently evaluating and looking for only OpenSource solutions, I found just one framework 
[STAF](http://staf.sourceforge.net/) , any help on pointing out other similar framework would be of great help

This is not for a web based application , but for a application using CLI & GUI interface & no proper API layer :(

Answer (score 2):

STAF is probably the best option for this sort of thing.  It has really good cross-platform support, thorough documentation, and has been pretty stable for years. It's also extensible if you need to customize the services for your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

STAF does seem to be the standard.  However if you have something which will handle the distribution for you then it is easy to hook up results gathering.  I might suggest starting with [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) which is actually a distributed build tool with some support for testing through the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) has a [remote testing library](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/RemoteLibrary) that uses XML-RPC to send commands from the testing framework to remote servers. It has sample remote servers in python and ruby.